# What is the proper way to set up a always false IEqualityComparer<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, iequalitycomparer

I have a case where two objects can be compared many different ways for equality. For example:

```
public class HeightComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person> {
   public bool Equals(Person x, Person y) {
       return x.Height.Equals(y.Height);
   }

   public int GetHashCode(Person obj) {
       return obj.Height;
   }
}
```

And I use these comparers in `Dictionary<Person,Person>(IEqualityComparer<Person>)` for various methods. How would you make a comparer that guarantees each person is unique? I came up with the following, but it runs slow since the GetHashCode() method often returns the same value.

```
public class NullPersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person> {
   public bool Equals(Person x, Person y) {
       return false; // always unequal
   }

   public int GetHashCode(Person obj) {
       return obj.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

I could return the same value of `0` from `GetHashCode(Person obj)` but it still is slow populating the dictionary.

**Edit**

Here is a use case:

```
 Dictionary<Person, Person> people = new Dictionary<Person, Person>(comparer);
 foreach (string name in Names)
 {
     Person person= new Person(name);
     Person realPerson;
     if (people.TryGetValue(person, out realPerson))
     {
         realPerson.AddName(name);
     }
     else
     {
         people.Add(person, person);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you better describe your use case? It's not really clear what you mean by "unique" or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Considered unique even if the collection you're hashing contains many dupes? Implement GetHashCode so it always returns a unique number (perhaps increment by one every time it is called). Then the hashtable won't need to resolve collisions so often.

Comment: @MgSam different objects in memory. Two references to the same person should be treated the same. But two persons with the same stats should be different if created separately.

Comment: If you just want to see whether they are are the same object in memory but otherwise false use `Object.ReferenceEquals()`.

Comment: Why does "`GetHashCode()` method often returns the same value"? Does the object have it's own `GetHashCode` implementation?

Comment: Is `Person` a class? If you haven't overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on it, then the default behavior is reference equality.

Comment: @mikez Person is a class, without default overridden `Equals` or `GetHashCode`

Comment: @Moop So `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a `HashSet` though.

Comment: @mikez I cannot get the value stored in the HashSet though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290443/how-to-access-the-reference-values-of-a-hashsettvalue-without-enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type has not overridden the `Equals` or `GetHashCode` methods then their default implementations, from `object`, do what you want, namely provide equality based on their identity, rather than their value.  You can use `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default` to get an `IEqualityComparer` that uses those semantics if you want.

If the `Equals` method has been overridden to provide some sort of value semantics, but you don't want that, you want identity semantics, then you can use `object.ReferenceEquals` in your own implementation:

```
public class IdentityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Would EqualityComparer<object>.Default be the same thing as your IdentityComparer<T> ?

Comment: If `Equals` was overridden, then `GetHashCode` should have been overridden as well. You can use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` to get the default implementation. This could reduce the number of collisions.

Comment: @Moop No, because `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are virtual, so they'd still end up calling the overridden versions of the appropriate methods.

Comment: @mikez Thanks, I knew that what I had would *work*, but would have a higher collision rate than would be desirable.  I wasn't aware of that method; edited accordingly.