# Get original value from HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

UPDATE:
Starting with .Net 4.7.2, [HashSet.TryGetValue - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) is available.
 [HashSet.TryGetValue - SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909955/199364)

---

I have a problem with `HashSet` because it does not provide any method similar to `TryGetValue` known from `Dictionary`. And I need such method -- passing element to find in the set, and set returning element from its collection (when found).

*Sidenote -- "why do you need element from the set, you already have **that** element?". No, I don't, equality and identity are two different things.*

`HashSet` is not sealed but all its fields are private, so deriving from it is pointless. I cannot use `Dictionary` instead because I need `SetEquals` method. I was thinking about grabbing a source for `HashSet` and adding desired method, but the license is not truly open source (I can look, but I cannot distribute/modify). I could use reflection but the arrays in `HashSet` are not `readonly` meaning I cannot bind to those fields once per instance lifetime.

And I don't want to use full blown library for just single class.

So far I am stuck with LINQ `SingleOrDefault`. So the question is how fix this -- have `HashSet` with `TryGetValue`?

Comment: It might help to provide a code example of what you have in the hash set and how you want `TryGetValue` to work!

Comment: TryGetValue would both return true/false whether it found the item in the set *and* the item that was present in the set if it found it.

Comment: Define your own `ISet<T>` facade around a `HashSet` private member.

Comment: Why do you want to use a hash set for keys where identity matters? Are you coding your own interning mechanism or something like that? Are you using `SetEquals` to compare to another set, or to another collection?

Comment: @Luaan, identity does *not* matter per se, I am pointing out, that equality is not identity. In other words the facts I found element equal to the one in hand, does not mean those elements are identical. I need `SetEquals` to check if the two sets are equal.

Comment: @greenoldman I understand that. I'm asking about the part where identity *does* matter to you - why do you need to read the value from the hash set rather than using the one you already have?

Comment: @Luaan, because each element not only holds data that are used to check equality, but also data which is not used for that and which are used for other purposes, so I cannot lose them, or swap them just because two items are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree this is something which is basically missing. While it's only useful in rare cases, I think they're significant rare cases - most notable, key canonicalization.

I can only think of one suggestion at the moment, and it's truly foul.

You can specify your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` when creating a `HashSet<T>` - so create one which remembers the arguments to the last positive (i.e. true-returning) `Equals` comparison it has performed. You can then call `Contains`, and see what the equality comparer was asked to compare.

Caveats:

- This holds on to references unnecessarily, so could end up preventing objects being garbage collected
- You'd potentially want to do this on a per-thread basis (if you've got a set that isn't *modified* after initialization, but is then *read* by multiple threads, for example)
- It assumes that `HashSet<T>` doesn't use any optimization such as "if the references are equal, don't bother consulting the equality comparer"
- It's fundamentally a horrible abuse

I've been trying to think of other alternatives in terms of finding intersections, but I haven't got anywhere yet...

As noted in comments, it would be worth encapsulating this as far as possible - I suspect you only need a very limited set of operations, so I'd wrap a `HashSet<T>` in your own class and only expose the operations you really need - that way you get to clear the "cache" after each operation, removing my first objection above.

It still feels like a horrible abuse to me, but...

As others have suggested, an alternative would be to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and implement `SetEquals` yourself. That would be simple enough to do - and again, you'd want to encapsulate this in your own type. Either way, you should probably design the type itself first, and *then* implement it using either a `HashSet<>` or a `Dictionary<,>` as an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you!!! Luckily I don't have the need to exposing this to the others, and I have single thread application (so far). The third point is easily solved -- if there is a match, and the comparer was not triggered, it means the element is found which was passed to the method. I will keep my question open for a while, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: If you go this route I would consider encapsulating this in a new hashset-type class so that you expose the methods that makes sense. This would make it easier in the future to discover that your current assumptions impose a limitation as well, like not being thread-safe. You could also mitigate the "hold on to references unncessary" problem by just always asking the comparer to clear its cache after use. In other words, don't spread the ask-hashset-check-comparer code all over the place, encapsulate it out of sight.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That's a very good point, yes. I'm still not sure I'd go down the route of really proposing the use of this anyway, but at least encapsulating it is a good start. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @greenoldman: Certainly keep the question open - and see my edit and Lasse's comment for improvements. It's still a really ugly hack :(

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Well, the OP specifically said "I cannot use Dictionary instead because I need SetEquals method." but they could reimplement that themselves, of course.

Comment: If memory and CPU performance is critical, this is a decent solution. I'd stay away from it otherwise. Although to be fair, the `HashSet` isn't thread-safe on its own either, and if you encapsulate it in your own type to hide the abuse, it *is* safe-ish. Just don't forget to also fix all those methods that have different behaviour for an argument that is a `HashSet`, or  you're going to lose performance anyway. Combining inheritance and composition is always such a pain :/

Comment: As the old saying goes "linearity killed the cat" :-), so horrible, not horrible, I implemented this idea and managed to shave off 1:20 min from 7:30 (not bad if you ask me -- of course I knew in advance linear searching through the set was the bottleneck). So thank you once again!

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should switch from a `HashSet` to a `SortedSet`

There is a simple `TryGetValue()` for a `SortedSet`:

```
public bool TryGetValue(ref T element)
{
    var foundSet = sortedSet.GetViewBetween(element, element);
    if(foundSet.Count == 1)
    {
        element = foundSet.First();
        return true;
    }
    return false;       
}
```

when called, the element needs just all properties set which are used in the Comparer. It returns the element found in the Set.

Comment: Thank you, good to have this approach as well in my "toolbox" :-).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you trying to use the wrong tool. True, you can save some memory using a HashSet but it seems to me that you are trying to acheeve a different goal: **Get the actual element that is just equal to a representation**.
So in reality they are two different elements. Just the [memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) (a unique representation) is equal.

Therefore you'd be better of using a Dictionary where you add your elements as *Key* **and** *Value*. So you're able to get it back (the identical) but you miss your `SetEquals`....

I suppose `SetEquals` in it's implementation does nothing much different than sequencially compare two HashSets in it's bucket order and fails on first non-equality.

So you should be equally good off using a simple `SequenceEqual()` (LINQ) comparing the two `Keys` collections.

So this extension method could do

```
public static SetEqual<T,G>(this IDictionary<T,G> d, IDictionary<T,G> e)
{
    return d.Keys.SequenceEqual(e.Keys);
}
```

This should work, because a `Dictionary` basically is a HashSet with an associated value. And more appropriate to your problem. (OK, to be correct, the code should go for `Dictionary<>` instead of `IDictionary<>` because Key order matters)

If you need an `IEnumerable<>` on the second parameter try sorting to get a defined order (not so efficient).

Comment: The implementation is different when you're comparing a set to another set - in that case, it can use a more direct and higher performing comparison. Otherwise, `SequenceEqual` is more or less equivalent.

Comment: Won't SequenceEqual also impose ordering? Two dictionaries that contains the same number of elements and have the same capacity might have the same key order but if they have different capacities that is definitely not the case. The ordering of dictionary keys is undocumented behavior.

Comment: You are just trading one problem to another -- and the end I still have problem. How to implement **efficiently** `SetEquals` on `Dictionary` keys (or values, does not matter, because in this case it would be a twin pair).

Comment: As said, order of keys or elements in a set is not guaranteed nor documented. True, the capacity influences it (haven't thought about that). So to be safe the only valid check would be ORDER + SequenceEquals. Ordering by Hash value might be a hint, but without it is not quite possible. I bet, even if you implement your own HashSet it will be a problem of the same compexity to verify Set-Identity. Due to the N x N combinations of equality. So CS has that solution of introducing an order and check then. => O(N)

Comment: Per your last comment, It would be good to *edit your answer* to show that some sort order needs to be imposed on the two sets of keys: not correct to directly compare the two key sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Finally added in .NET 4.7.2:

[HashSet.TryGetValue(T, T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[An SO post with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909955/199364)

Answer (score 1):

hopefully not blind but I haven't seen this answer anywhere. If you want dictionary's `TryGetValue`, you can just steal it.

```
theHashset.ToDictionary(item => item.ID).TryGetValue(key, out value)
```

All you need is a quick lambda for determining unique keys.

Comment: This whole topic is sprinkled with `Dictionary` -- Ctrl+F is your friend.

Comment: Obviously. Did I say I haven't seen anyone use Dictionary? No. I said I haven't seen this ^^^ answer. Ahhh CS people, as arrogant and snooty as ever. Gotta love'm.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see **this particular** answer because it is incorrect? `Dictionary` does not have `SetEquals` and I wrote abut it right in my question.

Comment: Incorrect how? Hashsets and dictionaries are easily interchangeable. just convert the result back to hashset and use hashset's setequals...

Comment: "Just convert" means extra memory allocation.

Comment: And? It's still a correct solution as far as I  can tell. Maybe not the most efficient,  but it's clean and easy, and I doubt whatever you're doing would necessitate something more efficient. Just nitpicking at this point to cover yourself.

Comment: Can you suggest any situation where this answer might be a useful alternative to what OP already said is his "fallback" solution, LINQ's `SingleOrDefault`? EDIT: I just thought of one:  if one wanted to make a significant number of TryGetValue tests, during a time when the set is not being altered, then it might make sense to create this dictionary, as the cost of creating it would be amortized over all those uses.

Comment: @greenoldman - IMHO, the other answers use dictionary quite differently. Here, the proposal is to *temporarily* create a dictionary in order to perform the TryGetValue. So that dictionary doesn't need SetEquals. This may or may not be a useful suggestion (I'm skeptical that anyone will actually do this), but it is indeed a new suggestion. [A related approach would be to simultaneously maintain both the HashSet and the dictionary.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, why you edited the answer instead of commenting it (with the added content)? The comments are exactly made for this purpose. Or simply answer the question. You cannot be upvoted, asked, edits serve another purpose -- to fix typos, clarify the question, etc.

Comment: @greenoldman - I'm confused by your question in the comment above. I didn't edit this answer. Are you referring to my edit on your original question? While I agree that is an unusual action to take, in this situation it was *vital* that anyone coming to this page be aware that .NET had been updated, so that they might not need to struggle with these old approaches; the benefit to future readers is the primary purpose of SO. Are we in agreement on the goal? Have I misunderstood your concern?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I am sorry, I meant "question". Sure thing, it can stay this way, but since it is in-place edit it is not possible to comment it.