# Can I retrieve the stored value x in a hashset given an object y where x.Equals(y)

Tags: c#, collections

```
[TestFixture]
class HashSetExample
{
    [Test]
    public void eg()
    {
        var comparer = new OddEvenBag();
        var hs = new HashSet<int>(comparer);

        hs.Add(1);

        Assert.IsTrue(hs.Contains(3));
        Assert.IsFalse(hs.Contains(0));

        // THIS LINE HERE
        var containedValue = hs.First(x => comparer.Equals(x, 3)); // i want something faster than this
        Assert.AreEqual(1, containedValue);
    }

    public class OddEvenBag : IEqualityComparer<int>
    {
        public bool Equals(int x, int y)
        {
            return x % 2 == y % 2;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int obj)
        {
            return obj % 2;
        }
    }
}
```

As well as checking if hs contains an odd number, I want to know *what* odd number if contains. Obviously I want a method that scales reasonably and does not simply iterate-and-search over the entire collection.

Another way to rephrase the question is, I want to replace the line below **THIS LINE HERE** with something efficient (say O(1), instead of O(n)).

Towards what end? I'm trying to intern a *laaaaaaaarge* number of immutable reference objects similar in size to a Point3D. Seems like using a `HashSet<Foo>` instead of a `Dictionary<Foo,Foo>` saves about 10% in memory. No, obviously this isn't a game changer but I figured it would not hurt to try it for a quick win. Apologies if this has offended anybody.

Edit: [Link to similar/identical post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494812/why-cant-i-retrieve-an-item-from-a-hashset-without-enumeration) provided by Balazs Tihanyi in comments, put here for emphasis.

Comment: The concept of "retrieving" a value from a `HashSet` is nonsense, so I'm quite confused.

Comment: He means getting an element that's stored in the hashset.  In the test method, the value is 1.

Comment: Could you use a `Dictionary<int, int>` instead that maps from remainders to original values?

Comment: @recursive, to "get" an element stored in the `HashSet` -- *what does that mean*?  Get it by index?  That is nonsense because `HashSet` has no order.  Get it by *key*?  That is nonsense because a `HashSet` is not a key/value map.  It's nonsense no matter how you slice it.

Comment: @KirkWoll: If you speak linq, then you can think of it this way: `hs.Single (x => predicate(x))`.  It's not retrieving a value by index or key, but by predicate.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? What is `y`?

Comment: Thanks Miserable Variable - corrected

Comment: @KirkWoll It would be useful as memory optimization over using a dictionary where key and value are always identical. Unfortunately the interface of `HashSet<T>` does not support this. One application of such a pattern is for getting a canonical instance of a type with custom equality.

Comment: This is a very good question, similar to this: [Why can't I retrieve an item from a HashSet without enumeration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494812/why-cant-i-retrieve-an-item-from-a-hashset-without-enumeration)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the reference values of a HashSet<TValue> without enumeration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290443/how-to-access-the-reference-values-of-a-hashsettvalue-without-enumeration)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, you can't.

If you want to retrieve the object you will need to use a `HashSet`. There just isn't any suitable method in the API to do what you are asking for otherwise.

One optimization you could make though if you must use a `Set` for this is to first do a `contains` check and then only iterate over the `Set` if the contains returns true. Still you would almost certainly find that the extra overhead for a `HashMap` is tiny (since essentially it's just another object reference).